# Reorganize Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following columns in a DataFrame:

```
    | invoice_number | client  | tax_rate_1_isp | tax_base_1_isp | tax_1_isp | tax_rate_2_isp | tax_base_2_isp | tax_2_isp | tax_rate_1_no_isp | tax_base_1_no_isp | tax_1_no_isp | tax_rate_2_no_isp | tax_base_2_no_isp | tax_2_no_isp | status  |
    |----------------|---------|----------------|----------------|-----------|----------------|----------------|-----------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------|-------------------|-------------------|--------------|---------|
    | #1             | client1 | 15%            |            100 |        15 |                |                |           | 0%                |               100 |            0 | 10%               |               200 |           20 | correct |
    | #2             | client2 | 0%             |            300 |         0 |                |                |           | 10%               |               100 |           10 |                   |                   |              | correct |
```

And I would like to reorganize the DataFrame so it looks like this:

```
invoice_number   client     tax_type   tax_rate   tax_base   tax   status
      #1        client1      isp          15%       100      15   correct
      #1        client1      no_isp       0%        100      0    correct 
      #1        client1      no_isp       10%       200      20   correct 
      #2        client2      isp          0%        300      0    correct 
      #2        client2      no_isp       10%       100      10   correct
```

where a new line is created for each group of `tax_rate`, `tax_base` and `tax` maintaining the same information for the rest of the columns and creating a new column that would specify which type of `tax` (`isp` or `no_isp`) corresponds to, which is identified in the column name of the first DataFrame.

The goal of doing this is at the end be able to create a pivot table from the data.

Is there an efficient way to do that?

What I am doing now, and it is pain, is to create different DataFrames selecting the columns that correspond to the same tax group, filtering those DataFrames to just select rows with data and appending those to a DataFrame that has the structure that I need.

What I shared is an example, however the actual data could easily have more than 50 tax groups...

Comment: could you add the two lines (for client invoice number #1 and #2) in the original format to be able to reproduce your expected ourput?

Comment: Please add some of your original data

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), it is impossible sopy.

Comment: Data added to original format